Salesforce Nonprofit Cloud. The SOAP method "findDuplicates" doesn't work for the PersonAccount object
Attempting to invoke the findDuplicates method for the PersonAccount object results in the following error:
Request:
curl --request POST \
  --url https://test.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/60.0 \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
  --header 'soapaction: ""' \
  --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <SessionHeader>
            <sessionId>*********.hePLYbE29XDUEWdcSfw7t7GhoK</sessionId>
        </SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <findDuplicates>
            <sObjects>
                <type>PersonAccount</type>
                <FirstName>Elliot</FirstName>
                <LastName>Terry</LastName>
                <PersonEmail>elliot.terry@example.com</PersonEmail>
            </sObjects>
        </findDuplicates>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>sf:INVALID_TYPE</faultcode>
            <faultstring>INVALID_TYPE: sObject type &apos;PersonAccount&apos; is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the &apos;__c&apos; after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <sf:InvalidSObjectFault xsi:type="sf:InvalidSObjectFault">
                    <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_TYPE</sf:exceptionCode>
                    <sf:exceptionMessage>sObject type &apos;PersonAccount&apos; is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the &apos;__c&apos; after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.</sf:exceptionMessage>
                    <sf:row>-1</sf:row>
                    <sf:column>-1</sf:column>
                </sf:InvalidSObjectFault>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

The result is the same for the PersonAccount__c object as well.
Given that Salesforce allows the creation of matching/duplicate rules for the PersonAccount object, it's surprising that the findDuplicates method doesn't work for it.


What could be the reason behind this limitation?
Are there any other ways to apply matching/duplicate rules created for the PersonAccount object?


A "PersonAccount" is an Account object. So you'd call the API with Account for sobjectype. The API will handle that routing (meaning if the list of objects is PersonAccount - apply only PersonAccount rules).
The UI presents it as its "own" option - but, the metadata, after saving, shows you that's it's still Account when saved for the sobject. You can inspect the MatchingRule in the API
/services/data/v63.0/sobjects/MatchingRule/{recordIdOfMatchingRule}
Which then shows the following - note SobjectType (and there's SobjectSubtype to denote PersonAccount):
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "MatchingRule",
        "url": "/services/data/v63.0/sobjects/MatchingRule/000000000000"
    },
    "Id": "000000000000",
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "SobjectType": "Account",
    ...
    "SobjectSubtype": "PersonAccount"
}

